# Spectrum of LEDs

Tags: led

How monochromatic is the light from LEDs? I want a set of light sources which will emit light of different wavelengths, as narrow a spectrum as practical.

How wide are the spectrums of typical LEDs?

Comment: Depends how "monochromatic" you want. It's spectrum would be like a bell shape around the main wavelength. The question is how well the bell "width" works for you. If you want a really narrow one, you will need to look into lasers.

Comment: I suggest that you do some research, start at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode at the bottom of the page are some spectral pictures. Not all LEDs are the same. Look at some LED datasheets, some have a spectral plot. Search on Google for "LED spectrum".

Comment: FYI, all light has a bandwidth, as true monochromatic sources do not exist.  You need to define how small of a bandwidth counts as monochromatic for your purposes. For illumination purposes, LEDs are usually considered monochromatic, for telcom applications, they are extremely broadband.  What is your application?

Comment: How about RGB(W) LEDs? That's basically 3-4 different wavelengths bundled to get whatever colourtone you want.

Comment: What sorts of wavelengths and spreads are you after?  If it's UV, I'm curious about your application, as I have done some scientific imaging in UV.

Comment: Some have a surprisingly un-bell-like spectrum, e.g. the ones I use around 370nm are almost flat over a 10nm bandwidth.

Comment: @ChrisH hi that's very interesting ... if you post a datasheet link I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I recall seeing in the late 1990s an electronics-magazine project to build a spectrophotometer based on an array of LEDs of various colors. Do you have something like this in mind?

Comment: @jonathanjo the datasheet for the [updated version](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/uv-leds/9053955/) looks narrower than what we measured (I work in a spectroscopy group; we use these LEDs for a photocatalysis project).  I'm not sure if the spec has changed since 2 generations ago, or if we got a flatter emission in practice.

Comment: @ChrisH that curve is pretty much bell-shaped.  Was the flat-top you mentioned from your own measurements?

Comment: @jonathanjo, yes, we measured it on our own spectrometer. It would take me a little time to track down the data because it was taken by one of my postgrads. This was also on an older model of the LED, which was less efficient and less robust; the improvements may well be due to better material growth (III-nitride growth is improving all the time)

Comment: @ChrisH, Are you sure you weren't saturating your receiver when you measured the flat-top response?

Comment: @ThePhoton absolutely sure, for several reasons, the main ones being that it's what I do all the time, and that it's a Fourier Transform spectrometer (UV-Vis-IR) so saturation doesn't look like that

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will be getting a narrow band, many LEDs have width of about 20 nm at 50% down from the peak; other LEDs have quite a wide band.  The datasheets for LEDs will give you a curve for those specific to a particular LED.

Here are the graphs of LEDs I chose for a scientific imaging project based on how narrow their bands were without resorting to exotic components. I wanted a selection of colours as narrow as possible (but cheap), and bought well-known manufacturers' parts with datasheets, which I summarised as follows:

[image]
(The 400 nm line is dotted because it was an estimate.  The others were traced from datasheets and normalised to give same height.)

If you need narrower:

- a laser will be better than 1 nm, and can be much much better. (Given as 0.85 in [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2337628.pdf) of cheapest laser at a distributor). Some "broadband" lasers have a linewidth of a few to about 10 nm ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_linewidth#Pulsed_lasers))
- some extrenely narrow bandpass filters are available, such as astronomical  sodium filter, which can have a typical bandpass of 0.05 nm.  Be warned they can be extremely expensive.

Comment: "a laser will be a few to about 10 nm" Sorry, but no. A laser will typically have a linewidth on the order of less than 1 nm, and rather closer to 0.1 nm. And you can get Single Mode lasers with linewidths in the .001 nm range.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast thanks for picking up on this, my mistake.  I've edited the answer to show that my numbers were a worst case for some lasers, and clarify the normal case.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a set of light sources which will emit light of different wavelengths, as narrow a spectrum as practical.

If you want as narrow as practical, you should use lasers. LEDs are intrinsically broadband light sources.

However you really should define a bandwidth you need. Too narrow will introduce problems such as speckle.

Answer (score -1):

Different WAVELENGTHS may be difficult.  Different COLOURS, achieved by mixing the output of three LEDs, red, blue and green, is easy, and cheaply available in a single package.

https://www.rapidonline.com/truopto-ostama5b62a-full-colour-5mm-led-60-diffused-72-9647?utm_source=AffWin&utm_medium=Affiliate&awc=1799_1579713939_2a7737a0902bbca9c2076b48d027e40a

Comment: The OP asked for a **set** of light sources of different colors, not a single light source of variable color. Furthermore, you only get different "colors" if you are using a human brain to observe them. Optical instruments and creatures with different kinds of color vision will not see distinct colors.